# DIV floated left with auto width to fit in MAN div with 980px width

Tags: html, css

I have those DIV'S

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
  <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
  <div class='div2'>content 2content 2</div>
  <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
  <div class='div1'>content 1</div>
</div>
```

Main div is fixed size = 980px, inside it i have DIV class'div1' its floated RIGHT and is fixed size. All i want DIVS with class DIV2 to be:
1. Floated left,
2. Auto width so thay will fill all the remaining size 740px, 
3. content inside 'div2' align center.

i have this CSS code:

```
.content { width:980px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:5px;}
.div1 { overflow: hidden; float:right; width: 140px;}
.div2 { float:left; width: auto; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:center;}
```

But i cannot achive 
2. Auto width so thay will fill all the remaining size 740px

Comment: if you you have `740px` left, so divide by 5, minus `1px` for border and give `width: 147px` to `.div2`

Comment: I cann't because some of the div with 'div2' may have content in them that is more than 148px width...

Comment: I don't think it's possible then, I don't want to say, but use table instead :)

Comment: it must be possible. i think, it is not that complicated...

Comment: I leave table at the last. I know how to make it with table...

Comment: set with javascript last `.div2` width to available space left.

Comment: Is number of div2 - various? If it's constant, you can set width=25% of (980-140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to do it with a table, and you probably know how.

```
<div class='content'>
    <table class="divs2">
        <tr>
        <td class='div2'>content 2</td>
        <td class='div2'>content 2</td>
        <td class='div2'>content 2content 2</td>
        <td class='div2'>content 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <div class='div1'>content 1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content { width:980px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:5px;}
.div1 { overflow: hidden; float:right; width: 140px;}
.divs2{ float:left; width:740px;  }
.div2 { border-right: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:center;}
```

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/UCJA3/

Comment: Yes it's working but setting style with a table is a little bit old-fashioned

Comment: I know that table isn't the best solution to do layout, but sometimes you need it.

Answer (score 0):

why not set **width: 20%** on **.div2** to ?

Answer (score 0):

First wrap the ".div-2"s in an outer container:

```
<div class='content'>
   <div class="div-2-wrapper">
      <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
      <div class='div2'>content 2 content 2</div>
      <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
      <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='div1'>content 1</div>
</div>
```

Now give the "div-2-wrapper" class a width of 840px (the total remaining space) and float it to the left:

```
.div-2-wrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 840px;   
}
```

Finally, give each "div-2" class a width of 209px. The reason you want them to be 209 and not 210 pixels wide is because each one contains a 1px right border. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A74PP/1/)